# How to paginate a table built with 2 arrays?

Tags: angularjs, pagination, html-table, angularjs-ng-repeat

```
var mainItems = [
   { 
    name: Car,
    subItems: [
       { name: SubCar1 },
       { name: SubCar2 }
    ]
   },
   {
    name: Food,
    subItems: [
       { name: SubFood1 },
       { name: SubFood2 }
    ]
   }
]

<table>
    <tbody data-pagination-id="tableItem" data-current-page="cItemCtrl.currentPage"
        data-dir-paginate="mainItem in cItemCtrl.mainItems | itemsPerPage: cItemCtrl.numberPerPage" 
        data-total-items="cItemCtrl.total" data-status="on">

       <tr data-ng-repeat="subItem in mainItem.subItems">
          <td>{{mainItem.name}}</td>
          <td>{{subItem.name}}</td>
       </tr>
    </tbody>    
</table>
<dir-pagination-controls data-pagination-id="tableItem" on-page-change="cItemCtrl.pager(x)"></dir-pagination-controls>
```

I'd like to know how paginate this table above, because the array of subItems is ignoring the filter "itemsPerPage" in "data-dir-paginate". I need a way 
to paginate controlling both arrays. Is that possible?

Comment: try this http://plnkr.co/edit/6PFCPuFrN6lfGHjHVwGf?p=preview

Comment: @XAVI Hi, your example don't have the second loop (ng-repeat or data-dir-paginate).

Comment: Nobody know help?